# UNIX Fork() Function

Tags: operating-system

How does the Child process generate using Fork() function.

For example: A process execute the code
             fork()
             fork()
             fork()

Total Number of "child" process created is/are ?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you just ran that code to see how many childs that is created?

Comment: Agreed -- question shows no research effort. (Also, the "how does `fork()` work?" and "what is the effect of calling `fork()` in this way?" are two separate questions, and it's ambiguous which is intended.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments..But I am looking for the execution concept of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in Main you did total number fork as shown below then total 2power(3) = 8 processes will be created so, 8-1 =7 child process

To view the Processes use ps on linux

Eg:

```
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <errno.h>      
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/wait.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>     

int main()
{
/*-------------your code part------------*/
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
/*-------------your code part------------*/
}
```

Comment: Is this the thing you wanted to know ?? If so, Please ask questions as commented above by other seniors as it helps in better understanding.